# How could they return the Infinity Stones in their "raw" form?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

There is this one little thing that I don't quite get at the end of *Avengers: Endgame*.

After Thanos was defeated, Captain took the stones back to where they were originally taken to "correct" the timeline. However we see that Cap has the 6 stones in their "Raw" form, but that is not how all of them were taken.

For example in 1970 Tony didn't take the Space Stone but the Tesseract, so I assume they extracted the Space Stone in the present (by breaking the Tesseract like Thanos in the Infinity War movie?).

So how could Cap return the stone to the rightful place when he actually needed to return the Tesseract? Or am I missing something here...

The same goes for the Mind Stone, which was inside the Gem on the Staff Loki had in the first Avengers movie.

Comment: It helps if you don't think about plot logic too much!

Comment: @Paulie_D I really enjoyed the movie and I think its great, also thoughts like this don't ruin it for me one bit, but still I can't help to wonder :)

Comment: same about eather

Comment: Also, touching the Tesseract sent Red Skull hurdling through space to Vormir, and the power stone nearly destroyed Quill...

Comment: Oh, this is a better way of phrasing [another question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99965/72100). I am unfamiliar with this community and do not know what the best cleanup protocol would be.

Comment: Presumably since they had a method to extract the stones from their various containers, they had a way to either reinsert them into the existing housing, or potentially recreate whatever housing was required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Infinity Stones be handled by humans but almost killed Peter Quill?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/how-can-infinity-stones-be-handled-by-humans-but-almost-killed-peter-quill)

Comment: @FabianRöling can't be duplicate if it was posted 3 earlier...

Comment: @BojanB 1. I didn't notice that. 2. It can, if that's the better question or already has better answers. And in this case it should, because there are no answers here and two there, one with +9 and checkmark.

Comment: @FabianRöling - you have a point here, technically it should have been discovered when the second question was posted - before it was answered, but that is a different discussion that should not be argued here. I have now read that question thoroughly one more time and IMO it is not a duplicate - as that question you posted, answers how the stones could be held by "normal" humans. This is not what I am asking...

Comment: @FabianRöling - In Infinity war it was necessary to get the stone from the Tesseract, Thanos did that by crushing/destroying the Cube. In Endgame we do not know how the space stone was extracted from the Tesseract - we only know that Tony and Cap took the Tesseract from 1970 and Cap had the space stone when he went to return the stones - to be accurate though he should have returned the Tesseract not just the stone... So that is my question, how can he do that, did he create a new Tesseract?

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand. My flag was already declined, so that's resolved.

Comment: The title asks how the stones can be "used", but the body asks how they can be "returned". These are two different questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Tesseract is a casing for the Space Stone. The Ancient One says that the Infinity Stones must be returned to keep the timelines stable, not that they have to be returned exactly as they were taken. As long as the Stone itself is in the right time, it doesn't matter *for the stability of the universe* that the Space Stone doesn't go back in the Tesseract.

> The Ancient One: I'm sorry, I can't help you, Bruce. If I give up the time stone to help your reality, I'm dooming my own.
>
> Bruce Banner: With all due respect, I'm not sure that science really supports that.
>
> The Ancient One: The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time. Remove one stone and that flow splits. Now, this may benefit your reality but my new one, not so much. In this new branched reality, without our chief weapon against the forces of darkness, our world will be over run. Millions will suffer. So, tell me Doctor, can your science prevent all that?
>
> Bruce Banner: No, but we can erase it. Because once we are done with the stones, we can return each one to it's own time line at the moment it was taken. So, chronologically, in that reality, they never left.

From [IMDB](http://%20Bruce%20Banner%20:%20I'm%20sorry,%20I%20can't%20help%20you,%20Bruce.%20If%20I%20give%20up%20the%20time%20stone%20to%20help%20your%20reality,%20I'm%20dooming%20my%20own.%20%20The%20Ancient%20One%20:%20With%20all%20due%20respect,%20I'm%20not%20sure%20that%20science%20really%20supports%20that.%20%20Bruce%20Banner%20:%20The%20Infinity%20stones%20create%20what%20you%20experience%20as%20the%20flow%20of%20time.%20Remove%20one%20stone%20and%20that%20flow%20splits.%20Now,%20this%20may%20benefit%20your%20reality%20but%20my%20new%20one,%20not%20so%20much.%20In%20this%20new%20branched%20reality,%20without%20our%20chief%20weapon%20against%20the%20forces%20of%20darkness,%20our%20world%20will%20be%20over%20run.%20Millions%20will%20suffer.%20So,%20tell%20me%20Doctor,%20can%20your%20science%20prevent%20all%20that?%20%20The%20Ancient%20One%20:%20No,%20but%20we%20can%20erase%20it.%20Because%20once%20we%20are%20done%20with%20the%20stones,%20we%20can%20return%20each%20one%20to%20it's%20own%20time%20line%20at%20the%20moment%20it%20was%20taken.%20So,%20chronologically,%20in%20that%20reality,%20they%20never%20left.).

I guess they decided that was someone else's problem.

Comment: I think that you flipped "Bruce Banner" and "The Ancient One" in your quote block.

Comment: @Raj Oops seems like it's wrong on IMDB.

Comment: Definitely Natalie Portman's problem when they inject her with a rock