# How does this character return this stone in its original form?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

When Tony took the stone from 1970, it was in the form of the Tesseract but at the end of the movie Captain America goes back to return the stone which is not its original form. How's this possible?

Comment: @Vishwa Hi, I just wanted to note that I think this question is not correctly marked as a duplicate. This question asks how it is possible to take one object (the tesseract) and then return another (the stone) and assume the timeline will be fixed. While the other question has to do with timelines - so in what why is this a duplicate question. Also the answer of the duplicate question doesnt answer the question posted here, at least not really... It is possible that we might never get an answer to this question.

Comment: I agree, I don't see how this is a duplicate. That other question is much more general, and does not address the issue of the stone itself vs the tesseract at all.

Comment: The same question could be said of the Aether / Reality Stone.

Answer (score -1):

If you're just looking for a **possible** explanation, I think he probably *did* have a Tesseract casing to contain the Space stone, just shrunk down and stored in his briefcase. He would've also brought with him a miniaturized Scepter to put the Mind stone in, a device to transfer the Aether back to Jane, a "tool of a thief" to lock the Power Stone back into the Temple, and possibly a spaceship to travel to Vormir (it's unclear why this was necessary since they seemed to be able to quantum-tunnel to other planets without issues, but perhaps Vormir is harder to travel to unconventionally because it's "in Celestial space", which in Marvel universes is *not* as redundant a term as it might sound).